# PostAsJasonAsync returns 502 Bad Gateway in Maui Blazor Hybrid app, but not in postman or in Blazor WebAsembly

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, maui-blazor, razor-class-library

I have two apps, that share code for posting with httpclient.PostAsJasonAsync in a common Razor library.
One is a Blazor WebAssembly and the other is a Maui Blazor Hybrid app.

In the Blazor Web assembly app, PostAsJasonAsync works as expected, and a new record i created in the database.

In the MAUI Blazor hybrid app, the same shared code returns 502 Bad Gateway. Does not matter whether I run i as a Windows App or a Android app.

In Postman everything is fine.

Anyone having a clue to what could cause this?

I can add that this older code works:

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<T>(element);
StringContent strc = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
sResponse = await Http!.PostAsync(sURI, strc);
```

while this one do not:

```
sResponse = await Http!.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(sURI, element);
```

Comment: Did you try to test this method with some other web api? In addition, the maui blazor run bases on the webview not the browser.

Comment: I'm aware that MAUI Blazor runs in a webview, and this is indeed why there could be a difference, thought I dont se why. No I have only testet it with my existing web api.

Comment: So you can try to test it with other web api or post an new issue on the github.